# Restoring Dell recovery disks while preserving Linux partition

Tags: system-recovery, recovery-disk

I have a Dell laptop dual-booting to Windows 7 and Linux.  I have through my own stupidity royally stuffed the Windows partition.

I have the set of recovery DVDs that I created when I first got the laptop, and I've successfully booted from them in a VirtualBox VM and ended up with a fresh (albeit virtualised) installation of Windows 7.

When I started the recovery process, there was mention of other partitions being preserved, but it was unclear as to whether non-NTFS partitions would survive the process.

The question is: **can I run the recovery procedure without risking my Linux partition?**

Comment: It really depends on the layout of the partitions of the recovery image.  Without that information we can't predict what might happen.

Comment: What about posing your problem to Dell support?

Comment: I did ask Dell, but got a vague 'well it should work, but we don't support that configuration, so who knows?'.  I was hoping someone here might have had a go :)

Comment: As for layout, they were created as part of the laptop's setup procedure when I first switched it on, which I presume is Dell-specific.

Comment: @Flup: Just to be on the safe side why not image your Linux partition, perform the recovery process, then restore Linux if required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much experimentation, tha answer is that a Dell DataSafe backup will *not* overwrite a non-Windows partition when it's restored from scratch.  As long as there is enough non-partitioned space on the disk, the restore process will use it to create a new Windows partition.